# Problems when shuffling an array of strings

Tags: vb.net, random, shuffle

I am attempting to shuffle an array of strings, below is the segment of code i have already. However, a problem with this code is that alot of the times it shuffles the content but excludes one value. e.g shuffling A, B, C, D it will do this: A, D ,  , C.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
Private rnd = New Random()

Public Sub Shuffle(ByRef List() As String)
    Dim Limit As Integer = List.Length - 1

    For i = Limit To 0 Step -1
        Dim j As Integer = rnd.Next(0, i + 1)
        Dim temp As String = List(i)
        List(i) = List(j)
        List(j) = temp
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: `Dim j As Integer = rnd.Next(0, Limit  + 1)`  not sure if it is related but you want to make sure each element is considered for swap at least once

Comment: You are not providing enough information (= original values in `List`), but your problem has most likely to do with the fact that the list contains a blank value which is being included in the shuffling.

Comment: Cannot reproduce - 500 reps and nothing was skipped/dropped.  Make sure you dont have any empties in your array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a simple and clean option you can shuffle a list of string this way:

```
Public Function Shuffle(source As List(Of String)) As List(Of String)
    Dim rnd = New Random(System.DateTime.Now.Millisecond)
    Return source.OrderBy(Function(item) rnd.Next()).ToList()
End Function
```

And here is the usage:

```
Dim list = New List(Of String) From {"A", "B", "C", "D"}
Dim result = Shuffle(list)
MessageBox.Show(String.Join("," , result))
```